# How to return network data fetched in another class back into Android MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, okhttp, oncreate

In MainActivity onCreate I invoke network class to handle request using okhttp3. I need return data from network class to use further in logic in MainActivity, the calling class. In debugging, return data from network class is correct, but when I want use return data in another expression in MainActivity the return data give null.

```
//In MainActivity
Network n = new Network();
n.network("baseLogic", "user", params);


if(n.resp == null){
        String resp = n.resp;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), resp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }else if (n.resp.equals("0")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Rei.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Below is the network classes called from within MainActivity.
We've built a URL from passed params.
The return is stored in a class variable on response then returned by the class.

```
public class Network(){

public String resp;

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    //resp = client.newCall(request).execute().body().toString();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(okhttp3.Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(okhttp3.Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
            }
            resp = response.body().string();
            response.close();
        }

    });

    return resp;
}
```

Debugging shows value difference
[image]

Attempted solutions:
1) I tried to find a method or process (android splashscreen) to pause the MainActivity thread so the Network class instance can return data for MainActivity on time.
2) Spinning off network class instance on a task or asyncTask.

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android how to get response string from Callback using OkHttp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31145811/android-how-to-get-response-string-from-callback-using-okhttp)

Comment: `public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements Callback { ... }`

Comment: What does implementing Callback mean? How do I get the return value?

Comment: `Callback` is the `interface` which `OkHttp3` notifies, when it has completed... just use the signature of the class which I've provided and implement those two methods. one answer in the linked question also show that.

Comment: debug again, if you are getting data in response or not, and rest callback stuff are basics.